# «Вал» и «волна» — родственны ли слова?

Tags: орфография, этимология, словообразование

*В**а**л* — это большая в**о**лна (И. К. Айвазовский, ["Девятый вал"](https://rusmuseumvrm.ru/data/collections/painting/18_19/zh_2202/)).
Как же получилось, что у слов *вал* и *волна* разные корни и, соответственно, разное правописание?

Comment: Уважаемая Римма Михайловна, благодарю вам(мне, конечно, более приятно обращение, "тебе". От "вам", тянет двуличием.), за ваше старание в правке и за интерес к вопросу. 
По видимому сайт направлен, в большей степени, на правописание общепринятого, нежели на изучение, либо понимание Русских слов.
Мне, как раз, интересно понимание и осознание. Ведь Русские слова, нужно и слышать, и видеть, и осознавать.
По сему, ещё раз, Благо дарю вам за помощь и вероятно покидаю этот сайт.
Может быть, вы сумеете рекомендовать сайт, нужной мне направленности? Буду вам, очень, признателен.

Comment: Уважаемый Aleksrod. Я попробую тоже вам ответить. На этом форуме обсуждаются разные вопросы русского языка, в том числе происхождение и значение русских слов.  В то же время здесь приветствуются сведения, изложенные в проверенных источниках и выводы, основанные на таких знаниях. Понимание и осознание слов, как я полагаю, без этого невозможно. 
Я дам еще один ответ по вашему вопросу (если его откроют заново), где дополнительно приведу краткие сведения по языковым группам – не надо забывать, что «латиноязычная»  и русская лексика принадлежат к одной индоевропейской языковой семье.

Comment: Соответственно,   не стоит  противопоставлять их друг другу,  когда приходится изучать общую историю.
Да, язык надо чувствовать и понимать, но и уважать его тоже надо, поэтому правописание не менее важно, и мы уделяем этому много внимания. Мы также приветствуем грамотно записанные вопросы, в том числе с точки зрения пунктуации.  Будем рады помочь вам в этом плане.

Comment: Уважаемые участники форума. Пожалуйста, переоткройте вопрос. Я хочу дать на него второй ответ.

Comment: Ну вот, Sharon, вопрос в конце-то концов и переоткрылся! (Мои и Ваши старания все-таки увенчались успехом.) Авансом поддерживаю автора вопроса — пусть **новый** _любознательный_ участник получит от Вас дополнительные разъяснения (да и все мы — тоже).

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте статью «Происхождение слова вал», и вам всё будет ясно. [https://lexicography.online/etymology/в/вал](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%B2/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB)

**Вал (большая волна).** Это слово в значении «большая волна» имеет индоевропейскую природу и родственно словам **волна (вал)**, валить.

**Вал (волна).** Было бы соблазнительной ошибкой счесть, что перед нами то же слово, что и в статье «Вал (насыпь)», но в переносном значении: движущаяся водяная насыпь. Нет, этот «вал» одного корня с «валить», «волна»; они образованы все **от древней основы «vol», «val», которая всегда выражала представление о движении, вращении.** От нее же родилось и третье русское «вал» — «вращающаяся ось» (например, «гребной вал» винтового судна).

А почему такое изменение: «вОлна» и «вАл»? **Оно произошло под влиянием ПЕРЕГЛАСО́ВКИ,** когда при образовании новых слов от корня согласные звуки его сохраняются, а гласные заменяются другими.

Таким образом, в корне слов ***вал*** (большая волна) и ***волна*** разные гласные А и О, хотя это исторически родственные слова.

**Вал (земляная насыпь).** Это существительное в значении «земляная насыпь» заимствовано из немецкого, где Wall восходит к латинскому vallum — «крепостной вал». Отметим для знающих английский язык, что и английское слово wall — «стена» восходит к тому же источнику.

Было у римлян и слово «интер(между)валлум» — «пространство между двумя валами»; из него получилось наше **«интервал».**

Comment: Из того что я прочёл, вывод, что Русский корень "вал", а "вол" это перегласовка. Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Нет, не совсем. И.-е. корень vol /val  со значением - вращать, катить, а о-с. основа - это vъlna, в древнерусском языке также  вълна с 11 века. А вот в других языках и-е. группы возможны другие гласные, например:wallen (нем.).- кипеть, бурлить, волноваться. Вал (большая волна) скорее от глагола вращать, катить. Большая волна как бы катится, движется. Таким образом,  вал и волна - это только исторически родственные слова, у них одинаковое происхождение.

Comment: корень vol /val со значением - вращать, катить, а о-с. основа - это vъlna, в древнерусском языке также вълна с 11 века. То есть привнесенное из латиноязычной лексики, а по русски кастрированный бык?

Comment: @Sharon Этот вопрос, как мне кажется, — яркий образчик для Вашей темы на Мете (https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/536/%d0%9e-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82). Подожду-посмотрю — чем же закончатся _мои старания_? P. S. Не "по делу", наверно, я там разоткровенничалась. Извините.

Comment: По вопросу семантики [пены валунов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/471750/195473): могло ли во времена Лермонтова слово "валун" иметь второе значение слова "вал" (большая волна)?