# Пена валунов / валуны пены

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, семантика

М. Лермонтов:

> ...едва сквозь него светился фонарь на корме ближнего корабля; у берега сверкала **пена валунов**, ежеминутно грозящих его потопить.
> ...мало-помалу отделяющийся от **пены валунов** и ровным бегом приближающийся к пустынной пристани…

Дополнительно: по запросу ["валуны пены"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%22&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsYbOwXe3-cN-AQYo4S5nAIpSNRyCQ%3A1658592361764&ei=aRzcYoOGLofargTRvIy4BA&ved=0ahUKEwjD3rKEso_5AhUHrYsKHVEeA0cQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=%22%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8B%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQoAFYoAFguwRoAHAAeACAAaICiAGiApIBAzItMZgBAKABAcABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz) Гугл выдаёт 7 результатов. Среди них:

> Каждую весну и осень к берегам озера волны снашивают на берег большие **валуны пены**.
> Пенное шоу — это большие **валуны пены** над головами и под ногами.

Викисловарь содержит только [одно значение](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD#%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0) для "валун":
окатанный обломок горных пород размером от 10 см до 10 м в диаметре.

Вопрос: какое значение у слова "валун" применительно к пене?

Comment: Скорее здесь или сравнение или инверсия. На мой взгляд инверсия. Потому что вряд ли можно сравнивать пену с валунами. Хотя...

Answer (score 3):

"*Валуны пены*" и "*пена валунов*" — это разные вещи.

*Валуны пены* — так много пены, что она аж комьями, похожими на валуны.
*Пена валунов* — так много валунов, что они издали похожи на пену. Это художественное. Так получается, если воспринимать напрямую.

*Пена* — пузырчатая жидкая масса. Пузырь круглый, валун тоже (по крайней мере, округлённый).

> какое значение у "валун" применительно к пене?

Субстанция округлой формы.

Update:
Какие ещё есть варианты понимания "*от пены валунов*":
1) *отделяющийся от пены валунов [из пены]*;
2) *от пЕны валунов = от валунов пЕны* (непрямой порядок слов), то есть:
*валуны пены => пены валуны*.

Update 2:
Из словаря:
**вал**
1. Длинная земляная насыпь.
*Крепостной вал.*
**2. Очень высокая волна.

*Пенятся валы.***

Во времена Лермонтова слово "валун" вполне могло иметь второе значение слова "вал". "Валун" происходит от "вал", "валить". Более того, даже слово "волна". Все эти слова связаны.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Да, валун — это обломок горной породы в виде большого округлого камня.

Большое куполообразное количество пены вполне можно сравнить с [валуном](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=-v7tHDECJo4BbM%252CPFHCJpUQIn5IGM%252C_%253BeQa-a4_eLVtk6M%252CPFHCJpUQIn5IGM%252C_%253BCQbv-NFoQMt2XM%252Cc0z-96Z7lEC-gM%252C_%253B4br-P_76tgJWfM%252CkRKlSIv-NRKLtM%252C_%253BgSKT8C7WVOFp5M%252CPmsAWm5Biw_afM%252C_%253B3pNbQeVxjsjvaM%252CLncvyVhRzlCWvM%252C_%253BlW4DTllrDmXALM%252Cb930GiWPD0-wBM%252C_%253BZtPlH_FeIcZSVM%252CyzE_h3bEjooN-M%252C_%253BadqbdEHXyK561M%252CMmH_pWZrZ-jNRM%252C_%253BEYcA7V6VX18RoM%252ChgS9HfMK9XU8ZM%252C_%253BE18BMP28eUqXmM%252Cxc-y16ygmpJAKM%252C_%253B6OuJIBfKbOYb5M%252CBBtpAInAbcOIGM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kSmWMSjn2e_xvq0x1dw3IKfSqUHpg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_tu7D1ZH5AhVh_CoKHQgUBZ4Q9QF6BAgDEAE&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1#imgrc=RWE-WcCP_3JFxM).
Имеются и другие *валунные* сравнения.

До своей постели я добиралась ползком, через **мягкие тряпичные валуны**, занявшие все пространство комнаты. [Ю. И. Андреева. Многоточие сборки (2009)]

> Бабка Дарья всегда говорила, что коз надо любить и что они, матушки, всю войну нас кормили. Но это не ей, а Петьке приходилось надрываться и таскать из степи огромные куски каменной соли, от которых потом руки разъедало в кровь. К тому же дурацкие козы слизывали эти **валуны** так быстро, что Петьке нестерпимо хотелось их всех убить.
> А. Геласимов. Степные боги

**2.** "Пена валунов — так много валунов, что они издали похожи на пену. Это художественное".

А вот словосочетание *пена валунов*, считаю, имеет прямой смысл: это пена, которая образуется в море во время шторма — [пена *от* валунов](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=S-Jj-Bu-sBeCsM%252CgzWBnoclQ03HwM%252C_%253B4-SxB54rSwiGwM%252CbuWvryHBVkO3yM%252C_%253BN6HQFJwD55edIM%252CnAVqdEyHBo29eM%252C_%253BZgCyq23i1mhuIM%252CbuWvryHBVkO3yM%252C_%253BDVaHUq8S_t7ayM%252CfGEsKL3YIwDPkM%252C_%253BAjB8RcWC7m1UmM%252Cpr4CthxLHkunCM%252C_%253BnkxJFdDFubC_LM%252CbuWvryHBVkO3yM%252C_%253BizhuQjJhJgvwEM%252CT13tZLw6tZeqlM%252C_%253BDFWPlTKzeVjJKM%252CbuWvryHBVkO3yM%252C_%253BqbD0EQWT3beEhM%252Cvu2_nAzfEcUdaM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kRctm4oSCawIroi2bEZCyxNckgaDw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJlf-O0pH5AhWxlYsKHQw0C1wQ9QF6BAgNEAE#imgrc=sBOX9N_lOYzAjM&imgdii=vq2Iv1m8XpQwOM) или пена *вокруг* валунов (валуны в море сами по себе никак не похожи на пену — ни издали, ни вблизи).

> ...он ходит себе целый день по прибрежному песку, прислушивается к однообразному ропоту набегающих волн и всматривается в туманную даль: не мелькнет ли там на бледной черте, отделяющей синюю пучину от серых тучек, желанный парус, сначала подобный крылу морской чайки, но мало-помалу отделяющийся **от пены валунов** и ровным бегом приближающийся к пустынной пристани...

Вот он, желанный [парус на горизонте](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=U-keaiXh52uOCM%252CSzEp-JfpKXDdUM%252C_%253BrELLBgBZhl7gQM%252CL7An8DMLrDeWfM%252C_%253Bpt_L_UCDpqaKBM%252CXSJKb4D60gJEtM%252C_%253BNBU1WiQA__DbvM%252CrBic8f2XYSqtVM%252C_%253BYXbCHmlLGSXSBM%252CLpaHg6SfvW2x5M%252C_%253Bs3xahhq6FwblRM%252CcFFqdzEAgiKoBM%252C_%253BZWldvYwZoooXRM%252CdZddzkw4H196PM%252C_%253BEDppADjx_OO8KM%252CcvuIVc7G63zeFM%252C_%253BlI7EjP3X5MZIEM%252CiHjj6QocA9djWM%252C_%253B76WjxTt5hTjzIM%252ClfWNKDIOP9QUBM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kSmpcq1fHF0272cPcRZsWLh8QNNRg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTk8LR3ZH5AhWItIsKHRd5DRMQ9QF6BAgQEAE#imgrc=NBU1WiQA__DbvM), который так похож на [крыло чайки](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%20%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&vet=1&fir=-2-qOiAsa10bJM%252CNnY7QcIzuqZ0oM%252C_%253B2iOI8fbHfVfYQM%252CH0xkEkQAh1e5CM%252C_%253BvbA19d2yUEoEvM%252C6UL2QnZlbDIEVM%252C_%253BIIuOexBdi7w0EM%252CYDg17rFg9QMQtM%252C_%253BrxhcZBoaucNRpM%252CSWX5nxP-g1chUM%252C_%253BCYDVvtMFBk0IdM%252CTCLRNeQfGzVjPM%252C_%253B6-6rwrlnk5Br2M%252CAvkTb1F3VT8U3M%252C_%253BNa1CvUIIUcFl2M%252CD8qu7_WN0BCFuM%252C_%253BevJ5R-W2qyZMJM%252CZlPRKy2b8rFpUM%252C_%253BOSBH2ky2mK-r4M%252CTCLRNeQfGzVjPM%252C_%253BcaBnIWI5LA5ZtM%252C-6GFvL0tTuKM0M%252C_%253BkrmQ0SNTJOkE0M%252ChdKA2gZZl4eV1M%252C_&usg=AI4_-kQDfHDvbXklgHGON0QP6PXq7OilUQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDlqjR35H5AhWE6CoKHQrwBCMQ9QF6BAgFEAE&biw=1366&bih=657&dpr=1#imgrc=-x0TSAJ45ikNBM), который постепенно пробирается через бурную пену от валунов — к пристани...

> Между тем луна начала одеваться тучами и на море поднялся туман; едва сквозь него светился фонарь на корме ближнего корабля; у берега сверкала **пена валунов**, ежеминутно грозящих его потопить ([см.](https://books.google.ee/books?id=RrGIDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA163&lpg=PA163&dq=%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=TIWeSsLJSm&sig=ACfU3U2fnM7w4LvIJ6rWdnUnpidTc0WcnA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRnY-o_pH5AhXrl4sKHYaVBZYQ6AF6BAgaEAM#v=onepage&q=%D1%83%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false)).

Во время бури лодка пробирается к берегу между горами волн, поднимается на их хребты и падает в пропасть пены, а вокруг валуны, грозящие потоплением.

Comment: *валуны в море сами по себе никак не похожи на пену — ни издали, ни вблизи* — представим 200 больших камней у берега, близко расположенных друг к другу, издали вполне может быть похоже на пузырьки пены. *пена вокруг валунов* — интересная версия, но так не очень получается, потому что тогда принадлежность: пена принадлежит валунам (*пена чья?*). А предлоги "от" и "вокруг" нельзя опускать. Вам не кажется, что "пена валунов" — это не совсем верно, если реальна именно пена? Разве это норма? Какой вопрос ставим между этими словами?

Comment: Чего нет реакции? Надо же выяснить.

Comment: Да я вроде уже всё *пообъясняла* в ответе. Почти двести лет прошло. Может, это авторское восприятие-решение, и только в одном произведении (больше ни у кого не встречала)? Оставим на завтра, если получится. Отбой. Всех благ!

Comment: Я про прокомментировать мой комментарий. *Может, это авторское восприятие-решение* — в этой фразе проблемы с согласованием, а это грамматика. Хотя да, раз 200 лет, то тогда такое могло быть нормой, но должны были поправить в современных изданиях.

Comment: Есть идея, что под "пеной валунов" Лермонтов понимал не "пену от камней", а "барашки на гребнях волн". Барашек -- пенящийся гребень волны / белый "гребешок" на морской волне / пенный гребень ветровой волны. Аргументы: 1) камни у берега не могут потопить корабль (волны вполне могут), 2) пена от камней нах-ся близко к берегу, а парус нах-ся далеко от берега (там нет пены от камней). Возможно, в 2-х местах Лермонтов перепутал "валуны" с "волнами".